# 2 ImageButton stacked in my RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a layout to obtain the following organisation:

```
 ___________________________________
|BT TV ---------SP------------ TV BT|
 ------------------------------------
 ___________________________   _____
|--------PB-------- BT BT BT| |BT BT|
 ---------------------------   -----

BT: Button
TV: TextView
SP: Spinner
PB: ProgressBar
 _
| |: layout
 -
```

Currently, my problem is that the 2 last BTs (bottom right corner in linearLayoutGetPOI) are stacked and I cannot find a way to solve it:
I chosed to use RelativeLayout because I want the progressBar to fill al the available space.

> 

```
    android:id="@+id/fragmentPlayMedias"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutAudioControl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradientbackground" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutPOIControl"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonPrevPOI"
                android:layout_width="55dip"
                android:layout_height="55dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:contentDescription="@string/label_ImageButton_prevPOI_content_description"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/prevpoi_img" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewPrevPOI"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:text="00"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerPOI"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewNextPOI"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:text="99"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonNextPOI"
                android:layout_width="55dip"
                android:layout_height="55dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:contentDescription="@string/label_ImageButton_nextPOI_content_description"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/nextpoi_img" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutAudioControl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/linearLayoutPOIControl"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/linearLayoutGetPOI" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonRewindMedia"
                android:layout_width="55dip"
                android:layout_height="55dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imageButtonPlayPauseMedia"
                android:contentDescription="@string/label_ImageButton_rewind_content_description"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/rewind_img" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonPlayPauseMedia"
                android:layout_width="55dip"
                android:layout_height="55dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imageButtonForwardMedia"
                android:contentDescription="@string/label_ImageButton_play_pause_content_description"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/pause_img" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonForwardMedia"
                android:layout_width="55dip"
                android:layout_height="55dip"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/label_ImageButton_forward_content_description"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/forward_img" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imageButtonRewindMedia"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutGetPOI"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/linearLayoutPOIControl"
            android:paddingRight="8dp" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonScan"
                android:layout_width="55dip"
                android:layout_height="55dip"
                android:contentDescription="@string/label_ImageButton_scan_poi_content_description"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/qrcode" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonMap"
                android:layout_width="55dip"
                android:layout_height="55dip"
                android:contentDescription="@string/label_ImageButton_poi_to_map_content_description"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_map" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

<!-- Other layouts-->

</LinearLayout>
```

So what's wrong in my layout?

Regards,

Comment: what does `bunked` mean

Comment: @tyczj It means "abscond or play truant from school or work" :P These `View`s dont wanna come to work. :D

Comment: May I have a suggestion to solve this problem please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/fragmentPlayMedias"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="vertical">

     <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
         ___________________________________
        |BT TV ---------SP------------ TV BT|
         ------------------------------------
      </LinearLayout>  

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margintop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="250dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal" >
          ___________________________ 
         |--------PB-------- BT BT BT|
          ---------------------------  
     </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="70dp" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginleft="10dp"
           android:orientation="horizontal" >
           |BT BT|
       </LinearLayout>  
     </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Lol, Hi Win, it's close to what I ended to do. I kept the Relativelayout for all of them, excepting for the last layout for which, like you, I switched to a LinearLayout and everything goes well now. Thanks a lot anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your bottom left RelativeLayout's layout_width is set to "match_parent" meaning your "bunked" relative layout isn't shown.

Comment: I don't think so, I did that to get the progressBar fill all the remainging space on the left and the right layout is shown, but the 2 buttons inside are stacked instead of being displayed side by side So I suppose that the problem should be in the right RelativeLayout no?

Comment: Hmm okay. Instead of using a Relative Layout on the last layout, use a Linear one with orientation="horizontal". I find that wrapping LinearLayouts inside a single Relative Layout builds most layouts correctly. You only need RelativeLayout when the children of that layout need to be aligned to eachother or their parent. EDIT: Ha! Looks like that's what you did anyway. Glad ya fixed it.

Comment: Yes! Thanks anyway Phiat.